# xmlstarlet insert fails without error message

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ChannelList>
  <channel>
    <tvg-logo>https://tvpmlogopus.samsungcloud.tv/platform/image/sourcelogo/vc/70/01/68/USAJ2200014K9_20201208T081550.png</tvg-logo>
    <group-title>Samsung TV Plus</group-title>
    <title>US | ION Plus</title>
    <url>https://live-news-manifest.tubi.video/live-news-manifest/csm/extlive/tubiprd01,ION-Plus.m3u8</url>
  </channel>
  <channel>
    <tvg-logo>https://od.lk/s/MF8yMjY0NDYwOTdf/Stirr_Blue_510x510.png</tvg-logo>
    <group-title>"STIRR TV",STIRR</group-title>
    <title>Electric Now</title>
    <url>https://dai.google.com/linear/hls/event/KsvJAc81Qoewj6opYso6Fw/master.m3u8</url>
  </channel>

</ChannelList>
```

I want to add some elements through a bash script using xmlstarlet. Based on what I've read, I've got this command:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -i "/ChannelList/channel/title/" -v "NewTitle" > channels.xml
```

When I run it, there is no error message, and it deletes the contents of the xml file. I thought that `-L` should edit the file in place, but it deletes the contents if I remove it or leave it in.
`-i` should insert, but it looks like I'm missing something.

When I run the command I get the `--help` contents on the screen and the xml file is empty. The file still exists. Not that it should matter, but it's running inside a docker container. XML file is owned by root, and has 777 permissions on it. (This will be resolved once I can get it to work)

Comment: `-L` (edit in place) and redirection are not compatible, the `-L` don't display anything but edit the file.

Comment: You specified the output file with `>`, but never specified the input file to edit. You got a usage message because you `-L` requires an input file. And you emptied the file because there's no output and you redirected the output.

Comment: You are trying to insert a `title` whereas `title` exists already. Do you want to update ?

Comment: @Barmar I thought that the file at the end was where I was putting the data. Do I need to say what the file is to add data to it, then tell it to output again? What my goal is, is to have another channel entry with all the various elements for another channel.

Comment: @Philippe I want to add another 'channel' entry with another 'title', and the other entries as well. I'm just starting with one thing so that I can learn how to do it. eventually I hope to build a script that can handle adding a new entry.

Comment: As [@Barmar said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77419681/xmlstarlet-insert-fails-without-error-message#comment136486762_77419681), the file at the end IS where the output goes thanks to the `>` output redirection operator but you didn't tell the command what the input file was  (like doing `vi > file` instead of `vi file`) and then you added `-L` to tell the command to edit the non-existent input file. You may want to just get rid of the `>` or you may need to remove `> channels.xml` and change `-L` to `-L channels.xml` but idk, I'm not very familiar with xmlstarlets options.

Comment: Regarding [I want to add another 'channel'...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77419681/xmlstarlet-insert-fails-without-error-message#comment136488158_77419681) - to be clear, this problem has nothing to do with what you want to do with `xmlstarlet` but instead with how you're calling `xmlstarlet` to do it. If you really didn't see a "Usage" message from `xmlstarlet` when you ran that command line then get a new version because the one you have is broken or investigate what in your environment is causing stderr to not appear on your screen.

Comment: @EdMorton He *did* get a usage message. That's what he meant when he wrote "I get the --help contents on the screen"

Comment: @Barmar ah, I missed that, thanks. I took their statement "When I run it, there is no error message" to mean just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `channels.xml` is the name of your input XML file, you can do in-place (`-L`) insertion by :

```
xmlstarlet ed -L\
    -s /ChannelList -t elem -n channel -v ""\
    -s "/ChannelList/channel[last()]" -t elem -n "tvg-logo" -v "NewLogo"\
    -s "/ChannelList/channel[last()]" -t elem -n "title"    -v "NewTitle"\
    channels.xml
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I was having issues with trying to insert and getting lost down that trail. Now that I see it, it makes more sense.